# How can we generate GeoJSON from SQL data with latlong

Tags: geojson, sql-server, geoexplorer

Is there any way we can create GeoJSON from SQL server table with Latitude & Longitude Data?

Comment: Does the table include a spatial data type (a geometry), or just lat/long fields?  Any other 3rd party addins like ArcSDE?  Can you explain your use of the "geoexplorer" tag?

Comment: @RyanDalton : Yes table has geometry column as well. No ArcSDE. We are going to use GEOExplorer for standard service run from sql. But if we manage to directly use GeoJson then we can by pass GeoExplorer bit for lite version of our application

Comment: You can use [GeoJSON.Net](https://github.com/jbattermann/GeoJSON.Net). I have no experience with it. But I'm planning to work with it. I'll let you know it's usefulness when I do.

Answer (score 4):

I have used the PostGIS code with success from [Bryan Mcbride's Github Page.](https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON)

It also contains a MySQL version of the code and can also be used for other geometries like polygon and line.

Dissecting essential parts of the code for you:

Basically the code gets an SQL Query from the table. If your table has the lat-long pairs, you can fetch the data from the table by changing this line

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, public.ST_AsGeoJSON(public.ST_Transform((the_geom),4326),6) AS geojson FROM mytable';
```

Also , in case, this part of code can be used as template to get the lat long data via a request variable, if you pass it as an array for example.

```
if (isset($_GET['ll_array'])) {
//process the ll_array here
}
```

Then the rest of the code changes the array format of the query result array into the typical geoJSON array format

```
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $properties = $row;
    unset($properties['geojson']);
    unset($properties['the_geom']);

    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => json_decode($row['geojson'], true),
        'properties' => $properties
     );

    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}
```

and sends the output as geoJSON

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: `from SQL server table`...

Comment: Should have specified MS SQL Server table in the question. The question can be interpreted as a generic one

Answer (score 0):

Following is a bit sample code using GeoJSON.NET 
https://github.com/jbattermann/GeoJSON.Net

SQL Data Loaded into dataset ds

```
var modelF = new List<GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature>();

foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var point = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point(new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition(Convert.ToDouble(dr["latitude"].ToString()), Convert.ToDouble(dr["longitude"].ToString())));
    var featureProperties = new Dictionary<string, object> { };

    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        featureProperties.Add(dataColumn.ColumnName, dr[dataColumn].ToString());
    }
    modelF.Add(new GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature(point, featureProperties));
}
var fcol = new FeatureCollection(modelF);
var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fcol, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(), NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

return serializedData;
```

Comment: Haven't tried it, but the GeoJSON.Net MsSqlSpatial contrib might be of help: https://github.com/GeoJSON-Net/GeoJSON.Net.Contrib

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 has FOR JSON clause that can be used to format results as JSON. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115062042/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2016/01/05/returning-spatial-data-in-geojson-format.aspx) is an example how to convert spatial columns to GeoJSON.

Comment: I know, but the geography data type is date from sql 2008 (r2) so this `for json path` does not work for 2008 r2, 2012 etc.